# rails association without an id, based on a complex key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a User class. Each user has many social accounts, but one of each type (Instagram, Facebook etc...). Each social account has posts, and each post has interactions (likes, comments etc...)

The interaction's "user" (eg. the commenter/liker) is defined by the commenter's username (`Interaction.first.username #-> 'myInstagramUserName'`), and the interaction's 'type' (whether it's an instagram -like or a facebook-like) is defined by the related post's related social account type (`Interaction.first.post.social_account.type #-> 'InstagramAccount'`).

Now, since not all likers or commenters are necessarily going to be in my user's table - only the ones that use my service, I want to associate those that are from the interaction.

User Class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :social_accounts
  has_many :posts, through: :social_accounts
  has_many :interactions, through: :posts
```

SocialAccount class:

```
class SocialAccount < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :interactions, through: :posts
```

Post class:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :social_account
  has_many :interactions, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :user, through: :social_account
```

Interaction class:

```
class Interaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_one :target_social_account, through: :post, source: :social_account
  has_one :target_user, through: :post, source: :user
```

**My Question**
Each interaction should have two users associated with it - the from_user (who 'liked' or 'commented') and the target_user.

The latter I managed to define via: interaction -> post -> social_account -> user.

The first association, however, is more complicated:
I need to find the user_id in the social account whose username is identical to the interaction's username, and whose type is identical to the interaction's post's social_account's type.
By use of validations in SocialAccount, there is only one unique pair of these allowed, so there should be only one match:

```
validates :type, uniqueness: {scope: :social_account_id}
```

Of course, if the user doesn't exist in social_accounts it should return nil.

**UPDATE**

Well, I managed to make some headway by adding the following to Interaction:

```
has_one :from_social_account, -> (me) { where('social_accounts.type = ?', me.target_social_account.type)}, primary_key: :social_user_id, foreign_key: :social_user_id, class_name: 'SocialAccount'
```

and:

```
def from_user 
  from_social_account ? from_social_account.user : nil
end
```

this allows me to now get the user associated with the interaction (the one who is the liker - not the one who was 'liked') via:
Interactions.first.from_user

I still wonder if there's a better way to skip the `from_user` altogether.

Comment: Can you precise your question because it's a bit unclear, what can't you do?

Comment: I updated with some advancement that I made - it might make it clearer.